# Linuxでの文字列削除

Tags: linux, bash, shellscript, sed

```
[[File:AAA.jpg]]
[[Image:BBB.png|5MB|2015]]
CCC.gif|1MB
[[ファイル:DDD.svg|5MB]]
```

上記のような沢山のファイルの情報が記述されたテキストファイルがあります。このファイルを下記のようにしたいのですがやり方が分かりません。

```
AAA.jpg
BBB.png
CCC.gif
DDD.svg
```

下記のコマンドでファイル名よりも前の文字を削除することは出来ましたが、ファイル名より後ろの文字の削除が出来ません。どうかご教授いただけませんでしょうか。

```
sed -i -e 's/\[\[Image://gi' -e 's/\[\[File://gi' -e 's/\[\[ファイル://gi' -e 's/\|*//g' -e 's/\]\]//g' filename.txt
```

Comment: sed ではなく、GNU grep で look-ahead を使って `grep -Po '^(\[\[.+?:\K.+?(?=(\||\]\]))|^.+?(?=\|))' file` などという方法も。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sedだけで済ませるなら例えばこんな感じで如何でしょうか。

```
sed -e 's/^\[\[//g' -e 's/\]\]$//g' -e 's/\([^|]\+\)|.*/\1/' -e 's/.*:\([^:]\+\)/\1/' filename.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

```
cat filename.txt | tr '[]:|' '\n'|sort | egrep -e '^[a-zA-Z]*\.[a-z]*$'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ sed -n 's/^\(.*[^a-zA-Z0-9]\)\{0,1\}\([a-zA-Z0-9]\{1,\}\.[a-zA-Z0-9]\{1,3\}\)\([^a-zA-Z0-9].*\)\{0,1\}$/\2/p' input.txt
```